# Push messages not received after using collapse key

Tags: android

I am trying to run the GCM demo project provided at android developer website.

I am using a servlet to run push the messages to my android device.

I have used TimerTask at the server side (servlet) to push the messages every 10 secs.

When I use the below code, it works fine. No mater, how many times I register/unregister. I get the pushed messages every 10 secs.

```
             Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .addData("data", "My custom message...")
            .build();
```

But when I use the collapse key, as shown in the code below, the server sends the message successfully but the device is unable to receive it.

```
             Message message = new Message.Builder()
            .addData("data", threadCounter + ". S: " + new java.util.Date())
            .collapseKey("xyz")
            .build();
```

In the above mentioned code, the device receives the msg 10-20 times and then not able to receive the messages for a longer period of time.

Any help